# Left function in c#

Tags: c#, string

what is the alternative for Left function in c#
i have this in

```
Left(fac.GetCachedValue("Auto Print Clinical Warnings").ToLower + " ", 1) == "y");
```

Comment: This isn't a full question- what is this Left function?  Why are you looking for an alternative to it?  What is your expected input/output?

Comment: Left in Vb.net..i have to convert this to c#.Now i got the answer tnaks

Comment: This is not a duplicate...the other question asks for a vb 6 function in a vb.net program. This question asks for a C# answer

Comment: Or: `return value == null ? value : string.Concat(value.Take(maxLength));`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about a function

```
string Left(string s, int left)
```

that will return the leftmost `left` characters of the string `s`. In that case you can just use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx). You can write this as an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Left(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        maxLength = Math.Abs(maxLength);

        return ( value.Length <= maxLength 
               ? value 
               : value.Substring(0, maxLength)
               );
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
string left = s.Left(number);
```

For your specific example:

```
string s = fac.GetCachedValue("Auto Print Clinical Warnings").ToLower() + " ";
string left = s.Substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: @Roland Illig: Yes, but as I mentioned, "I'll leave the error handling to you."

Comment: Edited to pass through null, empty and shorter than desired strings unchanged.

Comment: Thank you Clippy

Comment: It's still much more code than the one-liner from my answer. Also, in the "specific example" code you don't use the `Left` function at all.

Comment: See Also: Right function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782786/right-function-in-c

Answer (score 64):

It's the Substring method of `String`, with the first argument set to 0.

```
 myString.Substring(0,1);
```

[The following was added by Almo; see Justin J Stark's comment. —Peter O.]

Warning:
If the string's length is less than the number of characters you're taking, you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Careful: If the string's length is less than the number of characters you're taking, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: I use Math.Min to avoid the ArgumentOutOfRangeException:  myString.Substring(0, Math.Min(numberOfCharacters, myString.Length))

Answer (score 20):

Just write what you really wanted to know:

```
fac.GetCachedValue("Auto Print Clinical Warnings").ToLower().StartsWith("y")
```

It's much simpler than anything with substring.

Comment: You nailed it. Why has this best answer not 1000 points ?

Comment: Because I came too late to the party. The other answers were already there and had gained enough reputation, even if they didn't answer the _actual_ question, which was an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 10):

use substring function:

```
yourString.Substring(0, length);
```

Comment: Careful: If the string's length is less than the number of characters you're taking, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: I use Math.Min to avoid the ArgumentOutOfRangeException: yourString.Substring(0, Math.Min(numberOfCharacters, yourString.Length))

Answer (score -1):

```
var value = fac.GetCachedValue("Auto Print Clinical Warnings")
// 0 = Start at the first character
// 1 = The length of the string to grab
if (value.ToLower().SubString(0, 1) == "y")
{
    // Do your stuff.
}
```

Comment: This code does not handle the empty string correctly, it throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException in that case.