# Right Function in C#?

Tags: c#

In VB there is a function called Right, which returns a string containing a specified number of characters from the right side of a string.

Is there a similar function in C# that does the same thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 46):

**Update**: As mentioned in the comments below my previous answer fails in case the string is shorter than the requested length (the `Right()` in VB.net does not). So I've updated it a bit.

There is no similar method in C#, but you can add it with the following extension method which uses `Substring()` instead:

```
static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get substring of specified number of characters on the right.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Right(this string value, int length)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;

        return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(value.Length - length);
    }
}
```

The method provided is copied from [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/right) and you can get additional infos there.

Comment: VB.NET Right function won't fail if length parameter is greater than the string's length.

Comment: That can well be. The question is what result we wan't if we try to get more characters from the string that it actually holds. I personally prefer an exception. But you are right, for a 'perfect' copy of the method we would then have to validate the length first and check for null as well.

Comment: See Also: Left Function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574606/left-function-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 12):

There is no built in function. You will have to do just a little work. Like this:

```
public static string Right(string original, int numberCharacters)
{
    return original.Substring(original.Length - numberCharacters);
}
```

That will return just like `Right` does in VB.

Hope this helps you!
Code taken from: http://forums.asp.net/t/341166.aspx/1

Answer (score 10):

you can use all the visual basic specific functions in C#

like this :-

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(s, 10);
```

you will have to reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic Assembly as well.

Comment: this not a good way to do it. You should not rely on importing the VB assembly unless their is no other way.

Comment: also, the VB function relies on the c# Substring function, so really, might as well just extend the substring function. see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Strings.vb.html#0dbb15fffce19341 and when you click on `Substring` strings.cs is opened up!

Comment: its not C#s, its .NETs   .  The VB lib is an extension lib, and if you are porting VB code that makes a lot of use of the VB extension lib then this is a good way to go, or you can slowly rewrite it into vanilla .NET

Comment: For what it's worth , it's an interesting answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can call this function from C# by importing the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.

But don't. Don't use .Right() from VB either. Using the newer `.Substring()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to do a comparison like this in VB:

`SomeString.Right(4) = ".txt"`

you can use the following in c#:

`SomeString.EndsWith(".txt")`

but, if you need to do something with the return value, then use `Substring()` as mentioned in other answers.