# ForEach Substring Trim

Tags: c#

I have the following query:

```
Locations.ForEach(a => a.Name = a.Name.Replace(@"/", @" ").Replace(@"\", @" ");
```

What I like to do is if the Name has a length of greater than 31 characters, I like to trim upto the 31st character. Is there each easy way to do this with the .ForEach I have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left function in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574606/left-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Your above code doesn't compile.

Comment: That's not a query, it's a foreach loop... :)

Comment: Do you want to create a new list, or trim the current one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use a combination of the `System.Linq` extension method [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) to "take" the number of characters you want from the beginning of the string and [`string.Concat`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPiJb-xc_cAhU4CDQIHVZmCHEQFjADegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd784338(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw2oyOYWl54EMbWH5tMqc149) to combine those characters back to a string, and then use this for the new value.

Using your example:

```
int maxLength = 31;
Locations.ForEach(a => 
    a.Name = string.Concat(a.Name.Replace(@"/", @" ").Replace(@"\", @" ").Take(maxLength));
```

Or a full compile-able example:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    var locations = new List<Location>();
    var maxLength = 5;

    // Populate our list with locations that have an ever growing Name length
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        locations.Add(new Location {Name = new string('*', i)});
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Beginning values:");
    locations.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    // Trim the values
    locations.ForEach(l => l.Name = string.Concat(l.Name.Take(maxLength)));

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnding values:");
    locations.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or example with Substring:

```
  const int maxLength = 31;  
  Locations.ForEach(a => a.Name = a.Name
    .Substring(0, Math.Min(a.Name.Length, maxLength))
    .Replace(@"/", @" ")
    .Replace(@"\", @" "));
```